# GoDaddy, changing dns from another hosting just for the website

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, godaddy

I have a domain registered in Godaddy, and a hosting plan in a website called AspNix. Right now, the dns in Godaddy is showing the dns for aspnix, and i am hosting a website and email accounts in aspnix without a problem. What i want to do is to host the website in godaddy(created one with their website builder), but keep the emails in aspnix. I have really very few knowledge in dns and related subjects, so started googling. I found out that i should change the A zone dns for just the website, and by  keeping MX same, the emails should work.

My question is do i change the A Zone DNS record in Aspnix (where my hosting is), or change it in godaddy (where the domain name is registered, and shows aspnix nameservers).

Thanks

Comment: If aspnix hosts the DNS zone for your domain then any DNS changes need to be done on their name servers.

Comment: my godaddy account has the dns names for my aspnix hosting. and in aspnix control panel, i can see a list of dns zones (with different types and names, like ftp,mail,mla,www...). so i think i can say that the aspnix hosts the dns zone. ok, i will try that. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your records should be changed at `SOA` (Start Of Authority) `NS` (nameserver), as all queries for your domain name will start from there.

Comment: thanks, i did the changes on godaddy first, then removed the dns zone records (like www, ns..) from aspnix. and voila, it works. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If aspnix is set to be your active name servers, you'd have to make the changes on their side.
Oftentimes the MX record will be set to something like `mail.mydomain.com` - if so, it's important not to change the 'A' record for 'mail' - just change your 'www' A record and possibly the wildcard * A record if that one is set now.